# If X is uniformly distributed over $(-5,5 )$ find $P(|x|\gt 3)$

Tags: probability, random-variables

How I approached this question was taking the intergral from -5 to -3 of 3dx and then from 3 to 5 of 3dx to get 12. Did I do that wrong?

Also part b of this question says To find the density function of |x|, for this I just took the probability of -a <= X <= a. To do this I took the derivative of F(a)/da = 1 to get that it's uniformly distributed on (0,1).

I'm not sure if I'm correct, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did a mistake. Note that $3$ is not the density of $X$. As $X$ is uniformly distributed, $X$ has a constant density $f_X(x) = c$, for some $c \in \mathbf R$. As we must have 
$$ 1 = P(-5 \le X \le 5) = \int_{-5}^5 f_X(x)\, dx = \int_{-5}^5 c\,dx = 10c $$
we have $f_X(x) = \frac 1{10}$. Now continue as you did, we have 
$$ P(|X| > 3) = \int_{-5}^{-3}\frac 1{10}\, dx  + \int_3^5 \frac 1{10}\, dx = \frac 25 $$
For the density of $|X|$, let $a \in (0,5)$, we have 
\begin{align*}
   P(|X| < a) &= \int_{-a}^a f_X(x)\,dx\\
              &= \frac a5
\end{align*}
Taking derivatives, as you did correctly, we have 
$$ f_{|X|}(a) = \frac 15, \qquad a \in (0,5)$$
Hence, $|X|$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,5)$.

Comment: Thank you! That was very clear. I see where I made the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

$\int_{3}^{5}\frac{1}{10}dx + \int_{-5}^{-3}\frac{1}{10}dx= 4/10$

Comment: Why is it 1/10dx?

Comment: Uniformly between [-5,5] means that you have interval of length 10 where the variable can occur. As each is equally probable then 1/10. Or look at it that the probability has to sum to 1, so $\int_{-5}^{5}pdx = 10p = 1$, solving for p yields 1/10.

Comment: Ahh makes sense thank you.